# How does gcc know where boost is installed

Tags: gcc, libraries, boost

I installed boost using `sudo apt-get install` on Ubuntu. Later I did not have to give gcc the `I` flag alongwith the path to the boost libraries to use boost ! Nor did I do any `pkg-config --cflags --libs` of any sort. What is the mystery here ? How is gcc able to know where boost is and how is it linking to it automatically ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Boost is a mostly header-only library, so there is no library to link with (most of the time).

As for the headers, Ubuntu place them in `/usr/include/`, which is one of the include paths GCC use by default. So any `#include <boost/foreach.hpp>` will work out of the box on Ubuntu.

Comment: additionally, the lib files are stored in the /usr/lib folder by default

Comment: @RitwikG: Yes, but you still need to link to them explicitly.